# An exception occurred while analyzing a cell in the decomposition tree

Tags: performancepoint

I am facing an issue with decomposition tree in PPS

error: an exception occurred while analyzing a cell in the decomposition tree

how to fix this issue and what is the cause of this issue???

Comment: Do you have the latest hotfixes installed?  If so, what is the date of the hotfix?  What is in your application event logs?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing the latest service pack and cumulative updates to your SharePoint Servers and take a look at the any PerformancePoint hotfixes.

I had a similar issue with the decomp tree and opened a ticket with Microsoft. They determined that it was an issue with a Kerberos dll even though I was not using Kerberos in my environment.... Weird right. Here is the link to that [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969083). Maybe try installing it in your dev environment and see how it goes.

Here is a [post that outlines some other hotfixes](http://denglishbi.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/performancepoint-services-2010-pps-hotfixes/). Although it is dated it may help you.